# Add delay using rxjs before executing a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a subscription and need to run a function ( `getDetails()` ) after getting values from that subscription . But need a delay before calling that function. Currently I used `setTimeout()` event. But I need to convert it to rxjs way. Any suggestion to do it better way using rxjs?

```
this.dataQueryService
  .queryOneTable(request)
  .pipe(pluck('items'), take(1))
  .subscribe((data: any[]) => {

    //data handling logic

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getDetails();
    }, 200);
  });
```

Update:
I need a delay after handling data inside body.

Comment: so its not related to rxjs. you need a delay and dont want to use settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @BizzyBob answer, you can do it with `map`.

```
this.dataQueryService
  .queryOneTable(request)
  .pipe(
    pluck('items'),
    take(1),
    map((data: any[]) => {

      //data handling logic

      return handledData;
    }),
    delay(200)
  )
  .subscribe((handledData: any[]) => {
      this.getDetails();
  });
```

Comment: That `map` should be a `tap`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`delay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/delay):

```js
this.dataQueryService.queryOneTable(request).pipe(
  pluck('items'), 
  take(1),
  delay(200)
)
.subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.getDetails();
});
```

Comment: But bro I need a delay after handling data... not to whole body